# Query with a bunch of If

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a query field that gives a result text "Completed" or "Not completed" for a field FuncID. I need to create another expression with IFF(s) that what say that operator level 1-5 they are in based on what FuncID(s) are completed using the below formulas

```
FuncID 1 
FuncID 2 
FuncID 3 
FuncID 4 
FuncID 5 
FuncID 6 
FuncID 7 
FuncID 8
```

Operator 1 =
FuncID 1 **OR** FuncID 2 has to be completed

Operator 2 =
FuncID 1 **AND** FuncID 2 has to be completed

Operator 3 =
Four (4) of the eight (8) FuncID(s) has to be completed

Operator 4 =
Six (6) of the eight (8) FuncID(s) has to be completed

Operator 5 =
Eight (8) of the eight (8) FuncID(s) has to be completed

```
ElegibleLevel: Iff[FuncID]=1 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 1",0,

Iff[FuncID]=1 OR [FuncID]=2 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 1",0,

Iff[FuncID]=1 AND [FuncID]=2 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 2",0,

Iff(Count[FuncID]=3) = 4 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 3",0,

Iff(Count[FuncID]=4) = 6 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 4",0,

Iff(Count[FuncID]=5) = 8 AND [Expr1] = 1,"OPERATOR 5",0,
```

Comment: It's currently unclear what you're asking. If you're going to use such complex logic, I highly recommend you store these operator levels in a table, so you don't have them clogging up queries and can query the highest valid operator ID for a certain employee

Comment: I updated my post and made it less confusing

Comment: Please share some sample data, with expected output. Without knowing how you've stored the data we can't answer your question. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/7296893)

Comment: I could share the DB im working on... Im having a few other issues I needed help with anyway if so how?

Comment: Sorry, I don't do that. Downloading accdb files is a substantial security risk, and I will likely get too involved with improving it. There are other fora, like UtterAccess and Access Programmers that are better suited for that kind of localized guidance.

Comment: not sure what kind of data your looking for then...I showed you what Im looking for in my post. and you want me to redo....

Comment: ok I added a what im hoping will work expresion named ElegibleLevel: in my post, it just needs fixed up to work corectly. The counts in the for the last 3 arent correct and im not sure about the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im now calling a function that will be able to decide based on a count to see if I completed the requirements ect based on my querys outcome instead of all the Iffs.

```
Function SetLevel(lngFuncID As Long, lngEmpID As Long, varDateCompleted As Variant)

  Dim lngPosID As Long
  Dim lngEmpPosID  As Long
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strCriteria As String

  strCriteria = "EmpID = " & lngEmpID

  If DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 8 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 5""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 7 Then
      lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 6 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 4""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 5 Then
       lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 4 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 3""")

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", strCriteria) = 3 Then
       lngPosID = 0

  ElseIf DCount("*", "qryMetalShopEmployeeFunctions", _
       strCriteria & " And (FuncID = 1 Or FuncID = 2)") = 2 Then
       lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 2""")

  ElseIf lngFuncID = 1 Or lngFuncID = 2 Then
      lngPosID = DLookup("PosID", "tblMetalShopLevel", "Position = ""Operator 1""")
  End If

  If lngPosID > 0 Then

     lngEmpPosID = Nz(DMax("EmpPosID", "tblMetalShopEmployeeLevel"), 0) + 1

     strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblMetalShopEmployeeLevel(EmpPosID, EmpID, PosID, DateAchieved) " & _
            "VALUES(" & lngEmpPosID & "," & lngEmpID & "," & lngPosID & "," & _
              IIf(IsNull(varDateCompleted), "NULL", "#" & Format(varDateCompleted, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss") & "#") & ")"

        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  End If
```

End Function

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a database schema similar to this one (simplified):

[image]

To determine the *operator level* of an employee, we need only 2 calculated numbers per employee:

- the number of assigned functions out of all 8 possible functions
- the number of assigned functions out of only the first 2 functions

The first of these would be your `CountOfReqCompleted`. Both can be calculated using queries like this:

EmployeesFunctionsAll:

```
SELECT EmployeesFunctions.EmployeeID,
  Count(EmployeesFunctions.FuncID) AS FunctionsCount
FROM EmployeesFunctions
GROUP BY EmployeesFunctions.EmployeeID;
```

EmployeesFunctionsBasic:

```
SELECT EmployeesFunctions.EmployeeID,
  Count(EmployeesFunctions.FuncID) AS FunctionsCount
FROM EmployeesFunctions
WHERE (((EmployeesFunctions.FuncID) In (1,2)))
GROUP BY EmployeesFunctions.EmployeeID;
```

Finally, to calculate the *operator level* for each employee, we can join these 2 queries to the *Employees* table using a `LEFT JOIN` such that "all records of 'Employees' are returned". Instead of nesting several `Iif` functions, we can use the `Switch` function to accomplish the task:

```
SELECT Employees.EmployeeID, Employees.EmployeeName, 
  Switch(
    EmployeesFunctionsAll.FunctionsCount >= 8, "Operator 5",
    EmployeesFunctionsAll.FunctionsCount >= 6, "Operator 4",
    EmployeesFunctionsAll.FunctionsCount >= 4, "Operator 3",
    EmployeesFunctionsBasic.FunctionsCount >= 2, "Operator 2",
    EmployeesFunctionsBasic.FunctionsCount >= 1, "Operator 1"
  ) AS OperatorLevel
FROM (Employees LEFT JOIN EmployeesFunctionsAll 
  ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeesFunctionsAll.EmployeeID) 
LEFT JOIN EmployeesFunctionsBasic 
  ON Employees.EmployeeID = EmployeesFunctionsBasic.EmployeeID;
```